# Difference between add_filter versus add_action

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I was looking over my functions.php and wondering why CODE A uses `add_action` while CODE B uses `add_filter` ?
The main goal of CODE A is to **both include and exclude** specific categories.
The main goal of CODE B is to **exclude** specific categories.

Is it correct to use `add_action` for CODE A
and `add_filter` for CODE B?

**CODE A: Display specific category (called "featured") for homepage, instead of "the most recent posts"**

```
function featured_category( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category_name', 'featured' );
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array(60, 61) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'featured_category' );
```

**CODE B: Exclude "sponsored posts categories" for search results**

```
function search_filter($query) {

    if ( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array(60, 61) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'search_filter');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` is an action and not a filter. `$query` is passed by reference which is why CODE A works without returning anything.

CODE B returns `$query` but again that code works because query has been passed by reference. The return value of the hook isn't assigned to anything.

```
do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this ) );
```

`add_action` and `add_filter` are used in different contexts but the code is the same (`add_action` is an alias of `add_filter`). While both sets of code posted will work the correct usage is `add_action`.

Comment: Thanks, I will use `add_action` . But just curious, in terms of website speed, which will load a website faster, `add_action` or `add_filter` ? ---- Also, notice I used three `$query->set` above - does so many `$query->set` result in a slow website ?

Comment: `add_action` vs `add_filter` has no effect on speed. The exact same process is being performed. You're using the set method. If those are the options you need to set then that's what you need to do. You can't somehow combine them into a call. I'd have to look at the set method to be sure but I can't see it having any impact on performance (excluding the database query that is ultimately run of course).