# Wordpress filter Vs. action

Tags: wordpress

I have some code in my functions.php which you can see below. When I hook in using the action the function doesn't execute, but when I hook into the filter it does, could someone explain why and whats the best practice?

**ACTION**

```
// ADD £40 ON SUCCESFUL SUBSCRIPTION PAYMENT (EXAMPLE 1)
function custom_add_funds($user_id) {

    // get current user's funds
    $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );

    // add £40
    $funds = $funds + 40;

    // add funds to user
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_add_funds');
```

**FILTER**

```
// ADD £40 ON SUCCESFUL SUBSCRIPTION PAYMENT (EXAMPLE 2)
function custom_add_funds_two($user_id) {

    // get current user's funds
    $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );

    // add £40
    $funds = $funds + 40;

    // add funds to user
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
add_filter('processed_subscription_payment','custom_add_funds_two');
```

Answer (score 0):

Both functions have different functionalities.
**Actions** are event based. suppose you want to call a function after submitting a form or page load in that case you will use add_action function.

whereas **Filters** are used to change the current flow. like a page have content "hello this my test content", and you want to show "hello **world** this is **yours** test content" to do so you will use filters.

for further details you can see following links:

[Difference between add_filter versus add_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458037/difference-between-add-filter-versus-add-action)
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120339/difference-between-do-action-and-add-action